# FileUpload is Uploading same image with different names

Tags: asp.net, .net, datalist

I'm trying to upload multiple images using FileUpload in ASP .net using following code:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in fuScreenshots.PostedFiles)
                    {

                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

                        fuScreenshots.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Screenshots/") + ID + "/" + fileName);

                    }
```

But it is saving the first image with names of other images in the server.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]
Kindly help me to find the cause of this issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer. It should be postedFile instead of fuScreenshots.PostedFile.

Correct code is below:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in fuScreenshots.PostedFiles)
                    {

                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

                        postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Screenshots/") + ID + "/" + fileName);

                    }
```